# Set of integer non-negative matrices with positive diagonals

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

This is essentially a reference request/name inquiry. Is there a name for the set $M_k$ formed by $k$ by by $k$ matrices with non-negative integer entries and positive values on the diagonal? Related, are there any papers about these sets, or at least for $k=2?$

Comment: You might find something by searching for "symmetric contingency table".